# American Airlines 24-hour refund: how do I know if a ticket has "Sale-imposed nonrefundable taxes" or "Taxes we must pay whether or not you travel"?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, refunds, american-airlines, taxes

I read on the [American Airlines 24-hour refund policy](https://www.aa.com/i18n/customer-service/support/customer-service-plan.jsp#guaranteedfares) ([mirror](https://archive.ph/dDFUW)) that "sale-imposed nonrefundable taxes" and "taxes we must pay whether or not you travel" are not refunded (see quote below) when cancelling a ticket within 24 hours of the flight ticket purchase. How do I know whether my ticket has "Sale-imposed nonrefundable taxes" or "Taxes we must pay whether or not you travel"?

---

Quote from the [American Airlines 24-hour refund policy](https://www.aa.com/i18n/customer-service/support/customer-service-plan.jsp#guaranteedfares):

> When you buy a ticket on aa.com or through American Airlines Reservations at least 2 days prior to departure, you have up to 24 hours from the time of ticket purchase to request aa refund. The 24 hour refund policy applies to all ticket types, but you have to cancel your trip to get a refund.* Reservations booked as part of group block do not qualify for the 24 hour refund.
>
> AAdvantage<sup>®</sup> award tickets can be canceled anytime on aa.com. We’ll reinstate your miles and refund eligible taxes and fees up to 1 year after the ticket issue date, but you have to cancel your trip before your first flight departs. There is no fee to reinstate your miles.
>
> [Canceling flight and upgrade awards and reinstating miles](https://www.aa.com/i18n/aadvantage-program/miles/redeem/award-travel/award-travel.jsp#cancelingandreinstating)
>
> Refunds will be issued in the full amounts, less:
>
> - **Sale-imposed nonrefundable taxes**
> - Service charge for booking through Reservations
> - **Taxes we must pay whether or not you travel**

Example of American Airlines flight ticket price:

[image]

This is just a random example to show the price breakdown that one sees when purchasing a ticket on the American Airlines website. Sometimes the carrier-imposed fees are larger than 0. I'm interested in both domestic and international flights.

Comment: The [Department of Transportation's "Guidance on the 24-Hour Reservation Requirement"](https://www.transportation.gov/sites/dot.gov/files/docs/Notice_24hour_hold_final20130530_0.pdf) says the airline must offer a **full** refund.  I would question whether deducting taxes complies with this.

Comment: I've never run into this problem. All carriers I had to cancel within 24 hours refunded the full thing

Comment: @Hilmar Thans, [some carriers won't refund](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/172260/1810).

Comment: It sounds like they are just including language in the event that you paid taxes that they themselves wouldn't be refunded.  Who knows in what cases this applies, but I'm sure 99.9% of the time the taxes are refundable.